# MySQL - NOT NULL bit(1) column in view

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a column in a view that is both `NOT NULL` and a `bit(1)`.  I've read some other [posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PUZg.png) that suggest using`IF`, `IFNULL` or `CASE` to produce a `NOT NULL` column.  The problem with this approach is you get back an `INT` or another type.  I want a `bit(1)`.

Instead, I've created a function which correctly returns the `bit(1)` column that I want, but it is still showing as `NULL`.

```
#Suggestion from Alex - returns bit(1) NULL
CREATE FUNCTION `cast_to_boolean`(n integer) RETURNS bit(1)
BEGIN
RETURN IFNULL(n,0);
END

#Without IFNULL - returns bit(1) NULL
CREATE FUNCTION `cast_to_boolean2`(n integer) RETURNS bit(1)
BEGIN
RETURN IFNULL(n,0);
END
```

Here is an example showing both approaches do not work:

```
CREATE 
VIEW `sample` AS
    select 
        cast_to_boolean(0) AS `Resuult 1`,
        cast_to_boolean2(0) AS `Resuult 2`

    #now display the proc

    SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM sample;
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: could you remove all data that you don't need from your example, and explain just what do you need?

Comment: Alex,  I think the example is important since it explains what has been tried already, based on suggestions in other posts.  The title says it all, I need to force a column in a view to be bit(1) and NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your point, but just to return `BIT(1)` and never return NULL you can change your procedure to:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `cast_to_boolean`(n integer) RETURNS bit(1)
BEGIN
RETURN IFNULL(n,0);
END
```

Comment: Alex, did you try that and have it work?  I am still getting a  NULL value back - MySql 5.5.39 on Windows.  T3 - cast_to_boolean bit(1)  YES

Comment: Yes I did try. And as I said already the problem is I don't understand your goal. So you are trying to get BIT(1) type from your function? or to `seenull=NO` somewhere after view declaration? if your point to see null=NO you can continue your self, because I see no reason to get that done. since VIEW is just presentation of some data, it is not a table to insert. But keyword `NOT NULL` has sense for mysql server only for `INSERT` context, when mysql engine check inserting data to have not null value. So I would worry just about real data returned by function, which I did fix.

Comment: I do get bit(1) back, but the problem is the column in the view is still specified as nullable.  The reason I need it to be not null able is because the views are being used for code generation and columns that allow nulls and columns that do not allow nulls are handled differently by the code generation.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, is there a solution for this?

Comment: @IkerJimenez what is the exact issue? "same" is not very descriptive. What is your table schema? What do you want to achieve? Are you creating some stored procedure as well? Why? The best option - create new question on stackoverflow with all details and mention that here in comment so I can check and help.

Comment: I have a view that contains a left outer join between 2 tables. The column in the table that might be null is a tinyint(1). I have a `IFNULL(r.boolean_column, 0) AS boolean_column` as a column in this view. I've tried several ways trying to define this column as a tinyint(1) and NOT NULL in the view with no luck.

Comment: @IkerJimenez as I told. Create new post with all details (including current and expected result) and give me a link to that SO post.

Comment: @Alex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59948091/mysql-tinybit1-column-through-a-view