# MySQL Tinybit(1) column through a view

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a view that joins 2 tables. One of the tables has a column of type tinyint(1) representing a boolean value.

This table does not always have an entry when joining, so the view needs to take a value of 0 (false) when the row is missing.
I would like the view to expose a column of type TINYINT(1) and NOT NULL, since it will always have a default value of 0, but I haven't succeeded in doing so.

See SQL below that reproduces the issue.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST1 (
    ID bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10202961 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE TEST2 (
    TEST1_ID bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
    MY_BOOLEAN TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' 
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP FUNCTION get_tinyint_zero;
CREATE FUNCTION get_tinyint_zero() RETURNS TINYINT(1) RETURN 0;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_VIEW
AS
    SELECT 
        T1.ID AS ID,
        COALESCE(T2.MY_BOOLEAN, get_tinyint_zero()) AS MY_BOOLEAN
    FROM
        TEST1 T1 LEFT JOIN TEST2 T2 ON T1.ID=T2.TEST1_ID;

DESC TEST2;
DESC TEST_VIEW;
```

In TEST2

```
# Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra
'MY_BOOLEAN', 'tinyint(1)', 'NO', '', '0', ''
```

In TEST_VIEW

```
# Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra
'MY_BOOLEAN', 'int(4)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/igDh3aJEXRLZEkL7eNrcnc/0

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_tinyint(MY_BOOLEAN tinyint) RETURNS TINYINT(1) 
RETURN COALESCE(MY_BOOLEAN, 0);

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_VIEW AS
SELECT 
    T1.ID AS ID,
    get_tinyint(T2.MY_BOOLEAN) AS MY_BOOLEAN
FROM
    TEST1 T1 LEFT JOIN TEST2 T2 ON T1.ID=T2.TEST1_ID;
```

Comment: This one gets the type right, but it shows the column as nullable.

Comment: The funny thing is that defining the column as `TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'` works. It only shows as nullable, but it isn't: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uFBjLA62TN6T3yHtxsGj6Z/4

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [null-save equal operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_VIEW
AS
    SELECT 
        T1.ID AS ID,
        T2.MY_BOOLEAN <=> 1 AS MY_BOOLEAN
    FROM
        TEST1 T1 LEFT JOIN TEST2 T2 ON T1.ID=T2.TEST1_ID;
```

#### [Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uFBjLA62TN6T3yHtxsGj6Z/3)

Comment: `T2.MY_BOOLEAN <=> 0 AS MY_BOOLEAN` is wrong. `0 = 0` would return `1`!!

Comment: This is very close. Is there any way of making the type be a tinyint(1) instead of int(1)?